# lcd 16x2 replacement and or interchangeability

Tags: lcd

I need to replace a 16x2 LCD on a salt chlorinator display.

I searched the part number (GX1602KP) but can't find it.

I see alot of 16x2 lcd displays which look similar - are these lcd's interchangeable ?

Comment: Sometimes they are, sometimes they are not. It depends on the interface, pin layout, voltage levels, etc. Some modules may be compatible while others are not. They are not universally compatible though.

Comment: Timing varies sometimes too. Source: Replaced the 16x2 in a Siemens business phone and not all types worked.

Answer (score 1):

This Chinese site found searching for [GZ1602](http://product.dzsc.com/product/infomation/341982/13345220100809095014678.html) makes it look similar - according to Google Translate.

> Brand: GX Model: GX1602 Type: LCD screen Screen size: 2 (inch)
>
> The character type liquid crystal display module is a dot matrix liquid crystal display module specifically for displaying letters, numbers, symbols, and the like. It is divided into 4-bit and 8-bit data transmission methods. Provides a 5×7 dot matrix + cursor display mode. A display data buffer generator CGRAM is provided, and CGRAM can be used to store font data of up to eight 5×8 dot matrix graphic characters defined by itself. Provides a wealth of command settings: clear display; cursor back to origin; display on / off; cursor on / off; display character flicker; cursor shift; display shift. An internal power-on automatic reset circuit is provided. When the external power supply voltage exceeds +4.5V, the module is automatically initialized and the module is set to the default display working state.
>
> The display content is 2 lines, each line displays 16 characters, and each character size is 5×8 dot matrix.
>   Character generator RAM can be customized according to customer needs, in Japanese, Russian and other 12 different countries.
>
> The liquid crystal display module (LCM) has LCD colors of yellow-green, blue, and gray for customers to choose from.
>
> The backlight color of the LCD module is yellow-green, orange, white, red, emerald, and blue, which can be selected by customers.
>
> The use and storage temperature are: normal temperature (operating temperature 0 ~ +50 ° C, storage temperature -10 ~ +60 ° C); wide temperature (operating temperature -20 ~ +70 ° C, storage temperature -30 ~ +80 ° C); Temperature (working temperature -30 ~ +80 ° C, storage temperature -40 ~ +80 ° C), for customers to choose.

Comment: And the description is very similar to that of a display using a HD44780 controller chip.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few types of LCD controller chips and some have compatible commands and some don't. If the controller or command set of the original display is known, it can be replaced with a display with compatible controller that has an identical command set. The command set should be easy to verify with a logic analyzer. Or just take the most common type of controller (HD44780 or compatible perhaps) and try it.

Answer (score 0):

99% of 16x2 displays have identical interfaces. The only 'variable' is the contrast setting.

These are cheap enough to buy and try. Just make sure the physical dimensions match where you have to install.